# Using Model Builder to find the overlap of any 2 routes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

As you can see from the following picture, I want to use ModelBuilder to find the overlap segment between any two routes, and then I need to merge the overlap segment with the original route.shp with a feedback loop. In the end, I will have a shp file, including all the routes and all the overlap segment between any two routes. The model shown in the following picture works well without iteration since I just manually assign the Route 1 and Route 2 as the input for the INTERSECT.
[image]

Suppose I have 100 routes. I need to do the INTERSECT of Route 1 and Route 2, Route 1 and Route 3, ..., Route 1 and Route 100, and Route 2 and Route 3, Route 2 and Route 4, ..., Route 2 and Route 100, ..., Route 98 and Route 99, Route 98 and Route 99, and Route 99 and Route 100.

ModelBuilder doesn't allow us to do the nested iteration so I can't use two for loop in one model. I wonder if there is a way to do it in separate models to realize the thing I want.

I am not familiar with Python code.

Comment: Just to confirm, each shapefile has a single polyline in it?

Comment: Yes, 1.shp is for Route 1 and 2.shp for Route 2. Actually, I have a shape file, including all routes. Before the INTERSECT, I split each route into each shape file, so there is only one route in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the For iterator to construct FEATURECLASS names. In the example shown below your input route layers are called 1.shp, 2.shp, 3.shp...

*As a side note you should avoid starting featureclass names with numbers. Shapefiles may allow them but geodatabases do not. It's only going to cause you a world of pain at some later stage.*

[image: model showing use of for iterator]

Note the model only calculate value tools are constructing the name and returning a featureclass which can feed as inputs into the Intersect tool.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Actually, I made it by using Python code, which is much easier than the ModelBuilder.

Comment: I agree, often when you want something that is a little more complex, especially if it involves loops within loops, it is much easier to do it in Python. The model should be useful to others who do not program in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Merge in ModelBuilder then I think you should familiarize yourself with, and create a test model using, [Collect Values](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/collect-values.htm):

> The Collect Values tool is designed to collect output values of an
>   iterator or to convert a list of multivalues into a single input. The
>   output of Collect Values can be used as input to tools such as Merge,
>   Append, Mosaic, and Cell Statistics.

Comment: Thanks for your information. The Collect Values did improve the model, but I still wonder if there is a way to do the INTERSECT between any two routes. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.